Can I edit the CoE startup list from the PLC in TwinCAT?
does anyone have experience with modifying the startup list of an EtherCAT CoE device from the PLC? Or modifying the startup list over ADS?
I can't find any documentation describing this but it must be possible somehow. I mean the XAE is modifying it. Maybe I need to fire up the ADS monitor and see if I can log what happens under the hood when you modify a entry. I'm unsure on which target port to monitor in that case, any pointers there would be helpful also.

i am not sure about writing the startup list but you can access the COE setting by using port 65535 and the AMS net id of the IO, which is normally the same as the PLC except .2.1 instead of .1.1

for like two years ago i was trying to write the startup list, your best chance is to write a routine with the FB_Coe_Write but the data will only be stored in the actual device, that means if you replace the device the configuration will be lost, i suspect the start up list is stored  local and when a configuration is loaded this document is also loaded via ads

Could you check those Beckhoff documents, please?
Beckhoff FB_CoeWrite
Beckhoff Example program R/W CoE
